# Joda Datetime Constructor: Do I need to specify TimeZone for a String ending with Z?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, utc

My database stores all Datetime values as Strings in UTC. When I look at the strings they are like this

```
2013-05-28T01:38:13.000Z
```

1. According to [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), 'Z' represents the timezone offset. Since there is nothing after the 'Z' does that mean there is no offset and therefore it represents UTC time?
2. If yes, Do I still have to specify the TimeZone in the constructor? Since the string seems to be doing that already (saying that it is UTC time) ?

   ```
   DateTime myDate = new DateTime("2013-05-28T01:38:13.000Z", DateTime.UTC);
   ```

Is the second parameter neccessary?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You still need to pass a timezone (UTC).

The reason for this is that the string-only parameter will correctly extract the values of year, month, etc., but then interpret them as belonging to the default timezone, rather than parsing the Z+-x part.

(I'll admit it's a bit confusing.)

You can see more details in this other question [with call trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359447/jodatime-passing-a-string-directly-to-datetimes-constructor), as well as the comment below for a better explanation of the meaning of the Z

Comment: Thanks Diego. I have gone through the other question as well. So I understand we have to give the timezone to the constructor because 'thats how it works'. I wonder why it just can not interpret the timezone information from the string's Z+-x ? Also what is the significance of 'Z'. does it mean Zulu? I see whenever there is a +-x, there is no 'Z' in the string, why?

Comment: @Gadam - `Z` is indeed a reference to "Zulu", but also, it is part of the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) specification.  Offsets are also part of the spec, but you would never see *both* in the same string.  Additionally, there is a subtle difference between `Z` and `+00:00`, in that `Z` is *affirmatively* UTC, while `+00:00` *could be* UTC, but could also just be from a time zone that happens to have a zero offset at that point, such as `Europe/London` in the winter, or `Atlantic/Azores` in the summer, or `Atlantic/Reykjavik` year-round.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson. I hope the answer is updated to include your explanation of 'Z' as well.